# pandas.read_excel parameter "sheet_name" not working

Tags: python, excel, pandas

According to [pandas doc for 0.21+](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), `pandas.read_excel` has a parameter `sheet_name` that allows specifying which sheet is read. But when I am trying to read the second sheet from an excel file, no matter how I set the parameter (`sheet_name = 1`, `sheet_name = 'Sheet2'`), the dataframe always shows the first sheet, and passing a list of indices (`sheet_name = [0, 1]`) does not return a dictionary of dataframes but still the first sheet. What might be the problem here?

Comment: I had the same problem which was resolved after upgrading to 0.21

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like you're using the old version of Python.
So try to change your code

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_with_data, sheetname=sheet_with_data)
```

It should work properly.

Comment: check your version of pandas `pd.__version__` If .21 or newer, use `sheet_name` keyword parameter. If older version, use `sheetname` [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use `pd.ExcelFile`:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(file_path_name), 'rb'), sheetname = sheet_name)

file_path_name = your file
sheet_name = your sheet name
```

This does not for me:

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(file_path_name), 'rb'), sheet_name = sheet_name)
```

Gave me only the first sheet, no matter how I defined sheet_name.

--> it is an known error:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17107

Answer (score 1):

Try at Terminal, type the following first, then re-run your program:

`pip install xlrd`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem until I found this solution:

```
rd=pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name=['Sheet2']),
```

Here `excel_file` means "file name".

The filename should be the full path to the file.

Make sure to use two backslashes (`\\`) instead of just one!

In my case, this works.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use double quotes like this.

```
# Returns a DataFrame
pd.read_excel("path_to_file.xls", sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install openpyxl
```

The above command worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).