# Pandas cannot read specific Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Seems like this has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975866/pandas-read-excel-parameter-sheet-name-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) already, however, none of these solutions are working for me.

I'm trying to do

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('input.xls')
df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name="Sheet2") ## Also tried sheet_name = 1
```

No matter what, `df` in the end still contains the first sheet instead of the second. I'm on Python 3 and Pandas 0.20.1 (Anaconda distro). What am I missing? How can I load the second sheet into `df`?

Comment: try to use `sheetname` instead of `sheet_name`. `sheet_name` replaced deprecated `sheetname` in Pandas 0.21.0

Comment: That did it! Is the documentation incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> **sheetname** : string, int, mixed list of strings/ints, or None, default
>   0
>
> **Deprecated since version 0.21.0**: Use `sheet_name` instead

That also means that it used to be `sheetname` before the version 0.21.0
;-)